# Why is Greece not called in English by the name Hellas?

Tags: etymology, names

The Greeks call their country Hellas and themselves Hellenes.

The names *Greece* and *Greek* are of Roman origin and were adopted from Latin *Graecus* into old High German as *Crêch* and then in all Germanic languages the name was fashioned after the Latin -  Old English *Grécas*. (See OED extract below)

It has been the policy of the international community for many years to name new countries, (and rename old ones), to correspond with the way they are known to their own government and population. Thus *Abyssinia* became *Ethiopia*, the *Gold Coast* became *Ghana*, *Rhodesia* became (after partition) *Zambia* and *Zimbabwe*. (For a more complete list of name changes go to http://www.conservapedia.com/Renamed_countries.)

Since there may be some evidence that it was only colonists (presumably from Rome to Euboea) that assigned the name *Greece*, why do we continue to use that name and why not *Hellas*?  After all we no longer refer to the USA as *The thirteen colonies*.

> Forms:  pl.OE Cré(a)cas, Gré(a)cas, ME Greckes, Orm. Grickess, ME
>   Greks, Grekis, ME Grekys... (Show More) Etymology:  In branch I: The
>   Old English Crécas plural, corresponds to Old High German Chrêch ,
>   Chriech (Middle High German Kriech ), Gothic Krêks < *Krêko-z , an
>   early Germanic adoption of Latin Graecus , plural Graecī (see below),
>   the name applied by the Romans to the people called by themselves
>   Ἕλληνες . The substitution of k for g is commonly accounted for by the
>   supposition that the Germanic initial g , when the word was adopted,
>   still retained its original pronunciation /ɣ/ , so that k would be the
>   Germanic sound nearest to the Latin g . In all the Germanic languages
>   the word was ultimately refashioned after Latin, with change of k into
>   g ; hence Old English Grécas plural beside Crécas , Middle Dutch
>   Grieke (Dutch Griek ), modern German Grieche , Old Norse Grikkir ,
>   plural. In branch II the noun is an absolute use of Greek adj. The
>   Latin Graecī is < Greek Γραικοί, said by Aristotle ( Meteor. i. xiv)
>   to have been the prehistoric name of the Hellenes in their original
>   seats in Epirus. The word is apparently an adjectival derivative of
>   Graius, which is used in Latin as a poetical synonym of Graecus.
>   Recent scholars think the name may have been brought to Italy by
>   colonists from Euboea, where there is some evidence of its having
>   existed: see Busolt Gr. Gesch. I.2 198. (Show Less)  I.

Comment: Aristotle was the first to use the name Graeci (Γραικοί) in Meteorology, saying that the area about Dodona and Achelous was inhabited by the Selli and a people formerly called Graeci, but at his time Hellenes. From this statement of Aristotle it is asserted that the name of Graeci was at one period widely spread in Epirus and the western coast of Greece in general, hence it became the one by which the Hellenes were known to the Italic peoples on the opposite side of the Ionian Sea.

Comment: The colonists that are mentioned came _from Greece_ and went _to Italy_. So your USA comparison should be that modern Americans would refer to Europa by an old name.

Comment: At first I thought this situation was similar to _India_ which is also not called India by the inhabitants. However, your source mentions that presumably _Greek_ is an older name for _Hellene_, used by the people themselves, so the situation seems to be different.

Comment: @oerkelens And that 'old name' being...? But forgetting any analogy with the USA, surely the point is that *Graeci* was a name simply assigned to a very limited part of the country by incomers based on the fact that some of the people there 'used to be known' by that name.

Comment: It's seems only Norway has opted for a Hellenic rather than a Greek name, so to speak. http://www.thepressproject.gr/photos/capture1413889749.jpg

Comment: @WS2 - Yes, but for some reason Graeci was the name that they were known by, especially by the Romans..and that remained.

Comment: @Neil What a fascinating little map! How interesting that the near neighbours in the Balkans have names based on the Latin. Presumably this was because it was established long before the great 11th-century split in the Church between Eastern Orthodox and Rome, and this nomenclature must have survived throughout the history of Contantinople and the Byzantine Empire. Though in the area of Constantinople itself Greece is nowadays known by the presumably Turkish name of *Yunanistan*.  Anyway full marks to the Norwegians!

Comment: The name _Graeci_ was used by Greeks coming to Italy (incomers? they were coming into Italy, yes) to refer to the people in the country that they came from. It is not strange or uncommon that such designation over time comprises a larger or different geographical area than than initially. (Iran is named after the Aryans even though Aryans lived also in other places and in the country itself there are plenty of non-Aryans).

Comment: The Norwegians' neighbours don't call their own country _Sweden_, by the way. I don't think this phenomenon is very uncommon.

Comment: My comment is not restricted specifically to Greece's situation. A few general points occur to me: *1)* The inhabitants [iA] of A have no control over how people in countries B – N choose to refer to A or iA; *2)* Different ethnicities, maybe with different languages, may all live within the borders of A. If their own designations differ, the name decided by the politically most powerful ethnicity prevails; *3)* Peoples may migrate; *4)* Countries adopting a new name must overcome much inertia when trying to persuade the many speakers of a juggernaut language like English to use their new name

Comment: @oerkelens I must confess to being a trifle confused as to who the colonists were, but I think that the first comment of Josh61 is of relevance here. Perhaps we should not get too burdoned with putting down colonists, but the main point seems to be that the *Graeci* applied to only a limited area, which included people who had once been known by that name. It is difficult to believe that the majority of Greeks welcomed the Romans calling them by that name.

Comment: @oerkelens Not the exact same name, but as least _Sweden_ and _Sverige_ are related, just with and without suffix, basically. A nicer parallel close to home would be _Germany/Deutschland_. Also note that in Norwegian, the adjective derived from _Hellas_ is still _gresk_, and a person from Greece can be called either _greker_ or _hellener_; so the switch is only half-hearted, as it were.

Comment: @ErikKowal Re 'the juggernaut', I can't think that any diplomat at the UN would dream of referring to *Rhodesia*, *Tanganyika*, or *South-West Africa*, nor for that matter *Palestine and Transjordan* for the land that calls itself *Israel*.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. I don't think we have resolved anything, and I have no idea what the new Greek government thinks about the matter. But it has been an interesting exercise, whilst I am stuck indoors with the snow falling in torrents (if that's what snow falls in!) in Manchester.

Comment: I said Sweden, I should have mentioned Finland of course... Suomi vs Finland.

Comment: @oerkelens I was never suggesting that Greece was the only example. The obvious large other one, of course is Japan. *Nihon* or *Nippon* means literally *the land where the sun rises*, and is of Chinese origin (as is much of the Japanese language). The English word *Japan* derives from a Chinese pronunciation of the same characters used by the Japanese to produce *Nippon*.

Comment: You think "Greece" is incorrect? At least it's based on historical fact. Y'all call Hungary by that name because 8th century writers couldn't keep their invading tribes straight.

Comment: @Marthaª Yes Hungary is another example like Finland, Japan etc of a country which is named differently in English to the way it is called by its own inhabitants.It should be *Magyarorzak* (apologies for accents missing), I believe.

Comment: @oerkelens Your mentioning of India, in a strange way, rather makes my point. The fact that native North Americans are, for obvious reasons, no longer called *Indians* means that people prefer not to be called what they are not.

Answer (score 3):

The name Greece is probably due to the dominance of Latin during the Middle Ages. Latin was the language of the Church and of science. Nicolaus Copernicus wrote his 
De revolutionibus orbium coelestium (On the Revolutions of the Heavenly Spheres) in Latin, published in 1543.

Comment: But the principal language of the Byzantine Empire was Greek, wasn't it? And before that the Roman Empire had been partitioned as early as the 3rd century by Constantine, between a Latin-speaking west and Greek-speaking east.

Comment: Yes, but Greek did not have the same importance as Latin in western Europe.

Comment: Indeed it did not. But one thing I find interesting, from the fascinating little map linked to @Neil's comment above, is that the name *Greece* is dominant in the Balkans and throughout eastern Europe generally, lands once part of the Byzantine Empire and before that the Eastern Church with its capital at Constantinople.

Answer (score 0):

Why do English-speaking countries not refer to Greece as Hellas? The same reason the French do not call The United States "The United States", nor do they call England "England". Every country is allowed to call other countries by the traditional name in their own traditional language.

Of course, if a new country is formed or an existing one renamed, other countries will usually adopt that new name (e.g. Bangladesh is no longer called East Pakistan, and Burma is (I think) now called Myanmar.

Some country names are impossible to pronounce in some languages; for example, Spanish does not have phonemes to replicate "Deutscheland".

Others are not so tough to pronounce (in English)  and I must admit switching to "Hellas" from "Greece" doesn't seem any harder than switching from, say, "Formosa" to "Taiwan". At least in English. I don't know about the other languages.

Comment: This answer is not merely wrong but absurd. Spanish doesn’t lack phonemes to replicate *Dóichlant*, nor do they refer to that country as **Alemánia* [*sic*] either.

Comment: My bad. My info about "Alemania" was very out-of date. But I can tell you that as recently as 1999, Honduran Spanish speakers could not pronounce my son's last name "Hitchcock" no matter how they tried.

Comment: I have no objection to *England* being called *Angleterre* by the French nor *Inglaterra* by the Spanish, since those words are direct translations of the word *England* in the respective languages. That is rather different to the position with Greece, Hungary etc.